# Determining ARIMA order from ACF, PACF, and Ljung-Box statistic

Tags: arima

The Initial Levels Data was:

```
Lag..    SACF    ..SPACF     ...Q*

 1 ...   0.991...    0.991...    521.70 

 2...    0.978...   -0.238...    1030.9 

 3...    0.966...    0.092...    1528.4 

 4...    0.955...    0.041...    2015.7 

 5...    0.945...    0.009...    2493.7 

 6...    0.935...    0.006...    2962.6 

 7...    0.925...   -0.025...    3422.2 

 8...    0.916...    0.075...    3873.6 

 9...    0.908...    0.043...    4318.3 

 10...   0.900...   -0.053...    4755.9 

 11...   0.891...   -0.024...    5185.7 

 12...   0.882...   -0.010...    5607.1
```

I have differenced the data to make it stationary and these are my results:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $SACF $\ \ $ SPACF $\ \ \ $ Q*

1 $\ \ $ 0.322 $\ \ \ $ 0.322 $\ \ \ $ 55.191

2 $\ $ -0.039 $\ \ $-0.159 $\ \ \ $ 55.986

3 $\ $ -0.111 $\ \ $-0.052 $\ \ \ $ 62.6

4 $\ $ -0.034 $\ \ \ $0.021 $\ \ \ $ 63.213

5 $\ $ -0.006 $\ \ $-0.02 $\ \ \ \ \ $63.231

6 $\ \ $ 0.006 $\ \ \ $0.005 $\ \ \ \ $63.254

7 $\ $ -0.103 $\ \ $-0.124 $\ \ \ $ 68.994

8 $\ $ -0.099 $\ \ $-0.026 $\ \ \ \ $74.309

9 $\ \ $ 0.03 $\ \ \ \ \ $0.07 $\ \ \ \ \ $ 74.792

10 $\ $0.065 $\ \ \ $0 $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $77.102

11 $\ $0.045 $\ \ \ $0.018 $\ \ \ \ $78.218

12 $\ $0.034 $\ \ \ $0.03 $\ \ \ \ \ $ 78.841

Could someone please explain to me how I can work out the ARIMA ($p$,$d$,$q$) model and how I can interpret the Ljung-Box ($Q$) statistic?

Answer (score 1):

Since the PACF(2) is "more significant" than  the ACF(2) this suggests an MA(1) model (0,0,1) . You might focus on the Q statistic for the suggested model as an attempt to test for sufficiency. This test is potentially flawed if you have pulses/level shifts/time trends in your residuals.

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful! This data is already differenced so should it be arima (0,1,1)? thank you!

Comment: yes ..... that would be correct

Comment: Thank you for all your help. My final question is why did you choose a (0,1,1) over a (1,1,0) if the PACF is more significant? Thank you

Comment: The idea is to look for "dominance" between the acf and the pacf in terms of number of significant ( or nearly significant ) values and the to use the weaker one to pinpoint the suggested  number of parameters. If the acf dominates then it is autoregressive. If the pacf dominates it is moving average. In your case it is nearly a tie and the results that you would get from a (1,1,0) would be nearly identical to a (0,1,1) as {1-.3b}=[1-.3b]**-1 more or less